# How to use SQLServer Service Broker/SQLNotifications with Delphi7?

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2008, delphi-7

delphi 7 and mssql 2008 are requirements I can't change for a new project I'm starting to work and if possible I'd like to get notifications/events if data changes on the server so I don't have to poll so the question is:

is it possible to utilize SQLService broker with D7 or is there something similar (was reading/thinking about crosstalk and ado.net but support starts only at D2007)?

**Update:** Just to be absolutely clear, I want to be able to get an Event if **data changes** in certain tables (eg. insert/updates on specific tables) and not if a table/database changes.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, is possible use delphi to access to the notifications and Events exposed by the MSSQL Service Broker. To do this you can use the [`WMI Provider for Server Events`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186371.aspx) which exposes a very rich set of WMi events and classes. If you are new to the WMI, I recommend you which read these articles [`Accesing the WMI from Object Pascal Code`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2010/12/01/accesing-the-wmi-from-pascal-code-delphi-oxygene-freepascal/) and  [`Delphi and WMI Events`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/04/18/delphi-and-wmi-events/) also you can use the [`WMI Delphi Code Creator`](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/wmi-delphi-code-creator/) to create an Delphi snippet to access the events of the `MSSQL Service Broker`.

Comment: hi, after some reading as much as I could, and from what I understand now, it looks to me that with WMI Provider you can't get an even if data changes on a specific table (eg. update tab1 set mod_date = getdate() where id = 1) but only if tables change (eg. alter tab1 add newcol int).

Comment: how should I proceed with this question - vote for close, delete or?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed answer. You can use the the `WMI provider for server events` not just for monitor DDL sentences, also you can monitor Trace Events (sql senteces which includes SELECT, INSERT UPDATES and so on) Check the MSDN Documentation for [WMI Provider for Server Events Classes and Properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186449)

Comment: thx - a lot has happened since I've asked about it (got a new job etc..). If I find a quiet moment I'll have a look again. Thanks.